# React Native: Rendering Component on Button Click

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a list of components that I want to render when the user clicks a button.  The screen is supposed to be a search screen where the user types in their query, and when they hit the search button a list of results is displayed.  However, when I try to make a component render using the onPress, nothing happens.  For this example I am just printing text instead of using map to print out components.

```js
renderResults() {  
   return <Text> Doesn't get printed </Text>
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          onPress={ this.renderResults.bind(this) } //use .bind(this) to access state in renderResults
          title="Search!"
          color="#841584" />
       </View>
      );
  }
```

Comment: You have to change the state of your component (or application) in the renderResults method. Now the renderResult method doen't trigger updating of state. If you'd like to change the state of component you have to call setState.

Answer (score 9):

```
export default class App extends Component {
    state={
      isVisible:false
    }

    renderResults=() =>{ 
      this.setState({
        isVisible:!this.state.isVisible//toggles the visibilty of the text
      })
    } 

    render() { 
      return (
        <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
          {this.state.isVisible?<Text> get printed </Text>:null}
          <Button onPress={ this.renderResults} 
            title="Search!" 
            color="#841584" /> 
      </View> 
      );
     }
}
```

Try this code.

and you can run the demo on [link](https://snack.expo.io/rkDlTKNU-)

Comment: I dont understand whats wrong with this answer to downvote.

Answer (score 3):

React doesn't know that it needs to rerender the view with this method. Instead, force a rerender by updating the local state. I would do something like `state = {buttonPressed: false}` in the constructor and then `this.setState({ buttonPressed: true}` in the `onPress`. Then just have a simple boolean in the render to either return the text or the button depending on whether or not the `buttonPressed` in the state is true or false

Answer (score 2):

Simple eg. by @Max Millington answer.  You can use [Conditional rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to check if state is true or false.

```
constructor () {
   super();
   this.state = {printText:false};
} 

showText = () => {
   this.setState({printText:true});
}

render() {
  return (
   <View>
    <Button
      onPress={() => this.showText() } 
      title="Search!"
      color="#841584" />
     {this.state.printText && <Text> Printed text... </Text> }
   </View>
  );
}
```